# When to block the data in an experiment?

Tags: statistics

I am currently studying Random Complete Block Designs and I would like to ask a question.

I cam across an example where we were able to conclude with the RCBD as significant, but regular ANOVA (done incorrectly) failed to identify the significance.

As I read the text it says that one can INCORRECTLY do the regular ANOVA without realizing that one has to block the data, things like this could happen.

Can someone explain to me when we are supposed to block the data?

Comment: Would receive better response at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ IMO.

Comment: thank you! I will use that from now on

Comment: Now answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396428/when-to-use-blocks.